# Android - create a map snapshot view like facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, google-maps, maps, snapshot

I have to show a snapshot of particular location in one of my app. I tried to find how to achieve this but no luck so far. It would be great if someone can share a tutorial or suggest on how to do this. Thanks in advance. I have also added an image for you guys to understand what exactly i want.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First ,assume you have the particular location,then you could have a Maker on it.
here is demo code to add a Maker:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
Marker newMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(location)
    .title("Hello world"));
```

Second,you should set the map's custom infowindow. demo code:

```
 //write a custom InfoWindowAdapter
 class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{

    private final View myContentsView;  
    MyInfoWindowAdapter(){
      myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {   
        TextView tvTitle = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.title));
        tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
        TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
        tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());   
        return myContentsView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
   }

 }

 //set the custom adapter to the map:
 myMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter());
```

if you want to set the maker relative to your project's object(such as User),you could keep a `Hashmap(Maker,User)` in the file.You could initial the Hashmap first with your data, then you can set the infowindow's info with specific user in the `getInfoContents(Maker maker)` via `Hashmap.get(maker)`.

here is the custom snapshot layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">    
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/snippet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

when click the maker,it will automatic show the infowindow,you can also show an info window programmatically by calling `showInfoWindow()` .